# Jquery not updating .html() for htmlstring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have set of html string and want to update the values of the string dynamical using a plungin I have already build.

Basically My plungin doing this,when I call it,it will normalize numbers and bind to the html using `$(this).html(newValue)`.But when I'm calling the plugin to process this html string its not binding the value.

here is my html string

```
 var htmlData = '<div class="clearfix">';
 $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       htmlData += '<div class="large-1 infographic-box border_right merged-top pull-left widget-data" >';
       $.each(value,function(dKey,dValue){

             htmlData += '<span id="'+dKey+'['+ key +']"  class="'+dKey+' value widget-data" data-value="'+dValue+'">'+ dValue  +'</span>';
                })
             htmlData += '<span class="headline">'+ monthNames[parseInt(key)-1] +'</span>'+
                                 '</div>';
            });
             htmlData += '</div>';
 $('.transaction-section').html(htmlData);
```

after this I'm calling my pluging

```
$(htmlData).find('.widget-data').each(function(){
                var value = $(this).text();
                $(this).siPrifixx(value,{
                    maxDigits: 4,
                    seperator: true,
                    decimal: 1,
                    popUp: true,
        });
 });
```

but values remain same, its not changing.What is the problem with my code.Can anyone help me to overcome this problem?

before calling the plugin `dValue` is some think like 1500000,I do normalize it into 1.5M in my plugin and it will overwrite the html value.But in this case its not working,But my plugin process with data,not append the value using `$(this).html(newvalue)`.`newvalue` is the formated value `1500000 to 1.5M`

Comment: Can you host your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what is your issue (which are the values that "remain same"?), but there is at least one thing that surely cause an error : you affect the `widget-data` class not only to the first embedded `<span>` but also to its wrapping `<div>`. In the latter case, in your pugin, `var index = $(this).attr('id');` will result in `undefined`.

Comment: before calling the plugin `dValue` is some think like 1500000,I do normalize it into 1.5M in my plugin and it will overwrite the html value.But in this case its not working,But I can see the normalize value in my plugin by `console.log(value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have work on it and find this.

```
 $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                  htmlData += '<div class="large-1 infographic-box border_right merged-top   pull-left " >';
                $.each(value,function(dKey,dValue){
                    htmlData += '<span id="'+dKey+'['+ key +']"  class="'+dKey+' value  widget-data" data-value="'+dValue+'"  >'+ dValue +'</span>';   
                });
                    htmlData += '<span class="headline">'+ monthNames[parseInt(key)-1] +'</span></div>';
            });
            htmlData += '</div>';

            $('.transaction-section').html(htmlData);
            $('.widget-data').each(function(){
            var value = $(this).data('value');
            var index = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).siPrifixx(value,{
                    maxDigits: 4,
                    seperator: true,
                    decimal: 3,
                    popUp: true,
                    countUp:index
                    })
            });
```

Thanks for every one who help me!